Excel VBA Userform: Scroll Bar location on Userform Load
Ok I have been scratching my head as to why this userform's scroll bar keeps starting at this location for some reason:

Here's the property menu for this userform and i'm not sure what I did wrong. I also am making sure that the userform's Developer mode state has the scroll bar fully scrolled up.
Any thoughts?


Are you sure that in the one of the initialization events (Initialize, Activate) isn't it a code line as Me.ScrollTop = x, where x is a number... Or maybe the event calls a function/sub containing such a code line. Try using Find in VBE (code) (for all project) searching for ScrollTop =...

I don't, it's mostly pulling data from the worksheet like these 2 lines: txt_PIProcessName.Text = ActiveCell.Cells(1, 6) cb_LISecLoc.List = Sheets("DataSources").Range("B2:B1036").Value

Is the user form picture done on VBE (design mode) or after is was shown? If shown/launched, does it look the same in VBE?

I can only guess (because the truth is hidden behind the blue box in your image), but it is likely that, when you show the form, a control gets the focus that is (fully) visible only when the form content is scrolled.
By default, focus is set to the control with TabIndex = 0. Alternative could be that you use SetFocus for example in the Activate-Trigger of the form.
Small test form with 2 Textboxes:
When focus is on the top textbox: Scrollbar is at the top.

Now setting TabIndex = 0 for the 2nd textbox (that is not completely visible)

Will show the form scrolled down


sorry hiding the actual interface Thomas but this is a big help. I set the TabIndex to 0 on one of the controls on the top of the screen and voila, it works. thanks!
